# How can I enable the Ubuntu windows store app for all users on my computer?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-store

So I have two user accounts on my computer, one that's personal and one that's for work.

I’ve noticed that after installing Ubuntu from the Windows store on my work account, I can’t access Ubuntu from my personal account. I really don't want to install again it on my personal account since I already have a lot of configurations and libraries installed on it from my work app, it would just take up unnecessary space. This is the error I get on my personal

> Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item.

How do I make it so that I can access Ubuntu from all users? I heard that changing any permissions within WindowsApps folder itself can cause errors, so I don’t want to do that.

Comment: Thanks for moving this over from Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of (at least) Github issues on this topic, with the first being a ["How can I do it"](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/2979) question (which is closed), and the second being the [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5151), which is still open.

That's the bad news -- It's not supported right now.

The good news it that there's a possible workaround mentioned (although never spelled out) in the "How" thread that *may* work for you.  I was able to get it to work, but it will depend on your work account.

To launch your work WSL instance from your personal account, do the following in PowerShell:

```
$username = "yourworkaccountname"
$password = Read-Host -AsSecureString "Password"
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @($username,$password)

Start-Process -Credential $credentials conhost.exe -ArgumentList "wsl.exe ~" -WorkingDirectory C:\
```

You can set this up as a script, of course, to make it more easily repeatable.

Note, I'm not sure this will work if it's a domain account.  In that case, reversing the process (setting up WSL under the personal account) *might* work.